# Loop between two sheets in excel and Enter data

Tags: excel, vba, loops

I want to loop through two different sheets the main sheet and the sub sheet. When the values in selected values in the sub sheet is matched with the main sheet type DBA team in the main sheet.

The code bellow works but skips some values;
how can i ensure it loops through both sheets?

```
Sub Test1()
Set lookUpSheet = Worksheets("MainSheet")
Set ServicesSheet = Worksheets("SubSheet")

lastRowServices = ServicesSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
lastRowLookup = lookUpSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
For i = 1 To lastRowLookup
portIP = lookUpSheet.Cells(i, 9)
 For s = 2 To lastRowServices
        'if found a match, copy column B value to sheet1 and proceed to the next value
            If ServicesSheet.Cells(s, 3) = valueToSearch And ServicesSheet.Cells(s, 4) = portIP Then
            lookUpSheet.Cells(i, 16).Value = "DBA Team"
            Exit For
        End If
        Next s

Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Can you provide an example of which value you are looking for which are skipped ?

Comment: I’m looping through list of ips and port numbers in the main sheet and check with the sub sheet if it’s matching then add text to the main sheet

Comment: You need to add how you are calculating `valueToSearch` to your post.

Answer (score 0):

You are not defining your list of ips.

You are looking for a single ip with different port numbers in every large iteration.

You should either look for the same couple of ip and port number :

```
Sub Test1()
Set lookUpSheet = Worksheets("MainSheet")
Set ServicesSheet = Worksheets("SubSheet")

lastRowServices = ServicesSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
lastRowLookup = lookUpSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
For i = 1 To lastRowLookup
portIP = lookUpSheet.Cells(i, 9)
valueToSearch=lookUpSheet.Cells(i,"the column of ips")
 For s = 2 To lastRowServices
        'if found a match, copy column B value to sheet1 and proceed to the next value
            If ServicesSheet.Cells(s, 3) = valueToSearch And ServicesSheet.Cells(s, 4) = portIP Then
            lookUpSheet.Cells(i, 16).Value = "DBA Team"
            Exit For
        End If
        Next s

Next i
End Sub
```

or look for each ip with combination of all port numbers :

```
Sub Test1()
Set lookUpSheet = Worksheets("MainSheet")
Set ServicesSheet = Worksheets("SubSheet")

lastRowServices = ServicesSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
lastRowLookup = lookUpSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

For j = 1 To lastRowLookup

valueToSearch=lookUpSheet.Cells(i,"the column of ips")

For i = 1 To lastRowLookup
portIP = lookUpSheet.Cells(i, 9)
 For s = 2 To lastRowServices
        'if found a match, copy column B value to sheet1 and proceed to the next value
            If ServicesSheet.Cells(s, 3) = valueToSearch And ServicesSheet.Cells(s, 4) = portIP Then
            lookUpSheet.Cells(i, 16).Value = "DBA Team"
            Exit For
        End If
        Next s

Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: I added this adjudgment but it always loops forever when i put a nested loop